# Is there a injective ring homomorphism between $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that there is a injective ring homomorphism if and only if $\operatorname{Ker} =\{0\}$. But how does this apply to the question?

Sorry, I made a typo. I typed "bijective" rather than "injective".

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Well if the kernel is {0} then f(1)=1 and f(2)=2. But then f(3)=f(0)=0=3 in Z_11. contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

One of those has $3$ elements; the other has $11$ elements. There's no bijective *anything* between them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so confused with abstract algebra and even forget the basic definition of "bijective".

Comment: Even when kernel is zero, one gets just an injective homomorphism. Consider the function on the ring of polynomials in a variable $x$ with integer coefficients  to itself which replaces $x$ by $x^2$. This is a ring homomorphism. But not surjective; $x^3+x$  will not have inverse image, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a typo. It's "injective" not "bijective".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Removed !

Answer (score 3):

No.

Let $f:(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)\to(\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)$ be a ring homomorphism.

Then $f(1)=1$, but $0=f(3)=3\cdot f(1)=3$, which is absurd.

So not only are there not any injective ring homormorphisms between the two, there aren't any ring homomorphisms at all between the two.

Ps. Obviously I am assuming that ring homomorphisms preserve unity. If you don't assume that ring homomorphisms preserve unity then the only ring homomorphism between the two is the zero map.

Comment: For rings with 1 this is true. If you relax that, the trivial homomorphism is always present.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, you have the trivial ring homomorphisms $f(x)=0$ which always exist, it should be "there exists no non-trivial homomorphisms"

Answer (score 0):

Do remember that for any ring $R$, ($R$,+) is a group. You get Lagrange's theorem just the same.

The image of your homomorphism must be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and so its order must divide 11. The only homomorphism you can form from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ has image {$0$}. Definitely not an injection.